# Vagrant/VirtualBox: how to create needed host-only ethernet adapter

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vagrant, host-only

Six years ago I set up a CentOS VM on a Win10 host, with mostly other people's knowledge - I was hanging on by a thread figuring out just enough to get it working. Now I'm moving all my stuff to a new computer (Win11). I installed VirtualBox and Vagrant, copied all the files I know of into the same paths as on the old machine, crossed my fingers, and gave it a shot. I got the following output:

```
PS C:\dev\7and7> vagrant up
Bringing machine '7and7' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> 7and7: Resuming suspended VM...
==> 7and7: Booting VM...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "797d2c9c-557c-4f5c-a988-502c3bcfae8e", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: Nonexistent host networking interface, name 'VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #4' (VERR_INTERNAL_ERROR)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole
```

Hmm, so I guess I need to create "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #4". In VirtualBox on my old machine, *File -> Host Network Manager* shows three such adapters - #2, #3, and #4. I don't remember whether I made them in VBox or by some other method. On the new machine there are none, but if I click "Create", it says "Creating host only network interface" for a couple seconds before ending with: "Failed to create a host network interface." The details say:

```
Failed to create a host network interface.

Assertion failed: [!aInterfaceName.isEmpty()] at 'F:\tinderbox\win-6.1\src\VBox\Main\src-server\HostNetworkInterfaceImpl.cpp' (76) in long __cdecl HostNetworkInterface::init(class com::Utf8Str,class com::Utf8Str,class com::Guid,enum __MIDL___MIDL_itf_VirtualBox_0000_0000_0046).

Please contact the product vendor!.

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: HostNetworkInterfaceWrap
Interface: IHostNetworkInterface {455f8c45-44a0-a470-ba20-27890b96dba9}
```

I don't understand most of that, but I know I don't have an F drive/partition (on either machine), and it's unclear what "tinderbox" could even be in this context (the internet thinks it's a note-taking tool). "Please contact the product vendor" - which product? Windows? VBox? Vagrant? My VM?

As you can probably tell, I'm way out of my league - can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm running VBox 6.1.36 and Vagrant 2.2.19.

EDIT: It occurred to me that the VM was suspended (not halted) when I copied it to the new host, so I halted it on the old machine and copied it again, and then tried to start it. This time I got different errors - first of all, Windows asked me no less that 5 times for permission for VirtualBox to access my hard drive - on the old machine it would never ask that at all when firing up my VM. Then the output was as follows:

```
PS C:\dev\7and7> vagrant up
Bringing machine '7and7' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> 7and7: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
Vagrant is currently configured to create VirtualBox synced folders with
the `SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate` option enabled. If the Vagrant
guest is not trusted, you may want to disable this option. For more
information on this option, please refer to the VirtualBox manual:

  https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders

This option can be disabled globally with an environment variable:

  VAGRANT_DISABLE_VBOXSYMLINKCREATE=1

or on a per folder basis within the Vagrantfile:

  config.vm.synced_folder '/host/path', '/guest/path', SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate: false
==> 7and7: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: E_INVALIDARG
VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage.exe: error: Assertion failed: [!aInterfaceName.isEmpty()] at 'F:\tinderbox\win-6.1\src\VBox\Main\src-server\HostNetworkInterfaceImpl.cpp' (76) in long __cdecl HostNetworkInterface::init(class com::Utf8Str,class com::Utf8Str,class com::Guid,enum __MIDL___MIDL_itf_VirtualBox_0000_0000_0046).
VBoxManage.exe: error: Please contact the product vendor!
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdecl handleCreate(struct HandlerArg *)" at line 95 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
```

So I guess it's Vagrant that is supposed to initiate the creation of the host-only adapter (when the VM is booted from powered-off state), rather than me doing it manually in VBox. Anyway, it's still not working.

Comment: The path is where VirtualBox source code was located on Oracle's automated build server at the time VBoxManage.exe had been compiled. Don't pay attention to it.

Comment: @user1686 Okay, I'll ignore that (a bit weird to be in the error message though). But I still don't know what product vendor I'm supposed to contact, or what else to do to solve this.

Comment: The error messages come from VBoxManage, so VirtualBox is the product and Oracle is the product vendor – and that part of the error message (with the path, function, etc) is meant to be forwarded to [the VirtualBox developers](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Bugtracker) so that they'd know where the crash occurred. (Overall, 'assert' type error messages aren't meant to be seen by end-users, they're more of a developer tool in the first place – programs use assert() to catch "impossible" cases where the developer forgot to add _proper_ error checking.)

Comment: Have you tried deleting the existing "host-only" network interfaces, just to check whether you're bumping into a limit of 4? (Also, when you say you had a #2, #3, and #4, was there a "#1" (not numbered) as well?) I very vaguely remember reading something in VirtualBox docs about 4 such interfaces being the limit on Windows...

Comment: @user1686 There aren't any existing ones at all on the computer giving me trouble. The #2, #3, and #4 I mentioned were on the OLD computer, on which "vagrant up" runs with no complaints. Thanks for the link to the Oracle bug tracker, but I'm not very hopeful - someone else reported that error four months ago with no response: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/20879

Comment: I tried to figure out the Win11 equivalent of the popular answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725779/failed-to-open-create-the-internal-network-vagrant-on-windows10 . In Settings / Network & Internet / Advanced Network Settings, there is a "VirtualBox Host-Only Network" (not a "bridged" one like in the SO answer), but clicking Disable doesn't change the button label to "Enable", so I don't think it's actually disabling. One commenter mentioned not having a physical ethernet port - is that relevant? My new PC doesn't have one either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those with similar struggles who might find this post...

I think the original cause of my problem was trying to restart a **suspended** VM after moving it to a new host that had never run VBox or that VM before. (When I did the move, I did not remember that it was suspended.) After that failed, I did `vagrant halt` on the old host and copied the halted VM to the new host in place of the suspended one, but by then the new host's settings had been goofed up. **Lesson #1: When moving to a new host, always completely shut down the VM first.**

As for the resulting low-level error messages, you can see in the comments on this question that I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/33733454 and tried to disable the "VirtualBox Host-Only Network" entry in *Settings / Network & Internet / Advanced Network Settings*, but it refused to be disabled. Apparently I was close to the solution at that point.

The final clue was here: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=100406&p=487497#p487353 To quote: *"Try rebooting your host so no Virtualbox processes are running, then go to your host's network adapters, where you can right-click on them and set properties or disable/enable them. Try disabling the Host-Only adapters then re-enabling them."* The clue I was missing was to reboot first and not touch VBox - that was not mentioned in the popular StackOverflow answer. Sure enough, after a reboot I was able to disable the Host-Only adapter and re-enable it. In my case, that cleared up the problem and my VM booted successfully. **Lesson #2: If you're getting weird errors related to your host-only adapter, reboot the host, then disable/re-enable the adapter in Settings or Control Panel, then try your VM again - the order is important.**